# What is な’ｓfunction in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

I have not seen な used with a noun in this manner before (I know it can be used with な "nouns" but I do not believe that 日曜日 is one of these) and was wondering what is the exact effect of な in this passage and if there are any particular grammar rules around its usage here.

今日は日曜日**な**ので銀行は休みです: Banks are closed because today is Sunday.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The grammar

Much as 古手梨花 described, ので is used to express a reason for something, similar to "because" in English.  Grammatically, ので is the conjunctive conjugation of のだ (plain form) and のです (polite form), which can be parsed as possessive or genitive の + the copula ("to be") verb だ or です.

の attaches directly to nouns or noun phrases, but because のだ describes reasons, it attaches to statements.  If you're making a statement about a noun, you finish with the copula だ or です.  And, grammatically, those statements that のだ attaches to must be in the 連体形【れんたいけい】 or "attributive" form, and the attributive form of だ or です is な.

Examples:

- 本です。 (It's a book.)
  ⇒ 本な[の]{●}[で]{●}[す]{●}。 (It's **because** it's a book.)
  ⇒ 本な[の]{●}[で]{●}読みます。 (I read it **because** it's a book.)
  *(Note the reversed clause order to produce a more natural English translation.)*

#### Your sample sentence

> 今日は日曜日なので銀行は休みです。

Basically, this is a longer sentence with a shorter sentence embedded.  Let's break this down like the simpler example further above.

- 今日【きょう】は日曜日【にちようび】です。 (Today is Sunday.)
  ⇒ 今日【きょう】は日曜日【にちようび】な[の]{●}[で]{●}[す]{●}。 (It's **because** today is Sunday.)
  ⇒ 今日【きょう】は日曜日【にちようび】な[の]{●}[で]{●}銀行【ぎんこう】は休【やす】みです。 (The bank is closed **because** today is Sunday.)

Answer (score 3):

「ので」 is used when we express resons (理由・原因). Connection (接続) of 「ので」 is 連体形 + の.

> ［接助］《準体助詞「の」＋格助詞「で」から》

「ので」 comes from 準体助詞「の」 plus 格助詞「で」, which means 「の」 could be seen as a noun here.

You might think 「日曜日**の**ので」 is the right answer, but it's just too difficult to say in daily converstion (because of the double の, it sounds weird), so we use 「日曜日**な**ので」 instead.