# 「年なんだから無理」How does one parse this colloquial sentence?

Tags: readings, parsing

This article
https://mainichi.jp/articles/20210920/k00/00m/040/036000c
contains the quote

「年なんだから無理」

which I understand to mean

*"The difficulties presented by your age are why it is impossible"*

How does one parse this sentence? Like this?

年【とし】age

難【なん】 (n,n-suf) difficulty; trouble; hardship

だから=です+から

無理【むり】impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

年 by itself can mean *old age*. From [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B9%B4_%28%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%29/#jn-158729)

> 人生の盛りを過ぎた年齢。老齢。

なんだ is a form of なのだ, essentially the same as だ.

- [Origin of the usage of な in ~なんだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66524/origin-of-the-usage-of-%E3%81%AA-in-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0)
- [コトバンク entry for なのだ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-589358)

Thus 年なんだから無理 means *Because (the woman is (too)) old, (her project is) impossible*.

Answer (score 3):

Sundowner's answer is good.

To build on that, I'd like to note that なのだ adds a sense of explanation that is missing from just だ.  Whereas だ is basically just *"[it] is"*, なのだ is perhaps closer to *"it is **because** [it] is"*.  [This other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66524/origin-of-the-usage-of-%e3%81%aa-in-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0/66541#66541) takes a deep dive into this structure in terms of grammar and meaning. [This other (shorter) post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82641/what-is-%e3%81%aa-%ef%bd%93function-in-this-sentence/82649#82649) contrasts the change in sense between です and （な）のです.